# Symfony Error: No route found for "GET /app/example"

Tags: php, symfony, windows-10

I have just created a Symfony application on my windows 10 laptop using the [Symfony Installer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html).

Then, I have started it with:

```
php app/console server:run
```

Then, I have opened http://localhost:8000/app/example as described in the documentation, but I get the following error message:

```
ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /app/example"" at C:\Users\JVerstry\morepath\Trunk\_symfony\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 2061
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check available routes with `$ php app/console  debug:router` console command. Is there `/app/example` exists?

Comment: No there is not, but there is /. I have just tried it and it works. I get the documentation needs an update. If you create a solution, I'll approve it.

Comment: I have reported the issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15559

Comment: Yes, it looks like you found a bug :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check available routes with next console command:

```
$ php app/console debug:router
```

It output all available routes, defined in your application.